# Magento googleanalytics.xml was missing

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

My Google Analytics wasn't working and I noticed googleanalytics.xml file missing but ga.php still exists (googleanalytics enabled on magento). Should I create new googleanalytics.xml file ? or it supposed to be generated automatically ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to recreate it.

I would also recommend  that you re-download the same version of magento and do a `diff` to make sure that no other core files are missing

Comment: SVN or some other revision control should also be used to keep track of codebase. I use it to keep an eye on core modifications so they can be stopped.